# ASP.NET session state not being shared in Redis

Tags: c#, asp.net, redis, session-state

We are planning to migrate from ASPstate to Redis to store session. We installed the Redis MSI package on one of the servers and the c# application is hosted on a different server. We have multiple web applications within single application hosted in IIS.

The configuration for both applications looks like this:

```xml
<sessionState mode="Custom" customProvider="MySessionStateStore" timeout="180">
    <providers>
        <add name="MySessionStateStore" 
             type="Microsoft.Web.Redis.RedisSessionStateProvider" 
             host="serverIP"
             port="6379"
             accessKey=""
             ssl="false"
        />
    </providers>
</sessionState>
```

Now the problem is that session is not being shared between applications. We checked the machine key and found to be same both applications.

Comment: Can you please post the config for each of your web apps?  It would also be helpful to post your IIS configuration as well.  Is it true that each of your applications is able to write to redis, but they can't share state?

Comment: <sessionState mode="Custom" customProvider="MySessionStateStore" timeout="180">
      <providers>

        <add name="MySessionStateStore" type="Microsoft.Web.Redis.RedisSessionStateProvider" host="serverIP" port="6379" accessKey="" ssl="false" />
      </providers>
    </sessionState>

Comment: same config for each application. I am sure that i have not configured or changed anything from IIS. I dont know whether we need to change any configuration in IIS or not.

Comment: Thanks!  Mainly what I wanted to know is how the applications were arranged in IIS - whether you were using multiple sites, or if you were just doing something simple like 2 apps under the default site.  Sounds like the latter.

Comment: @killthrush - As you have mentioned different web application are hosted within default website.

Comment: Found out the solution by adding application name in webconfig.